# Angular6 flex-layout not working after migrating from angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, angular-flex-layout

After migrating my application from Angular 5 to 6 , the flex-layout is showing following error.

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(72,67): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,39): error TS1109: Expression expected.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(79,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
>   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(80,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

I have refered to the community in github, and as they suggested, they suggested me to downgrade my rxjs to rxjs6.2 , but the issue still persists.
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/827

The error is being shown in style.d.ts file, i don't think its an issue in that file, however here is the file.

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */
import { DoCheck, ElementRef, KeyValueDiffers, OnDestroy, OnChanges, Renderer2, SimpleChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BaseDirective, BaseDirectiveAdapter, MediaMonitor, StyleUtils } from '@angular/flex-layout/core';
import { NgStyleType } from './style-transforms';
/**
 * Directive to add responsive support for ngStyle.
 *
 */
export declare class StyleDirective extends BaseDirective implements DoCheck, OnChanges, OnDestroy, OnInit {
    private monitor;
    protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
    protected _ngEl: ElementRef;
    protected _renderer: Renderer2;
    protected _differs: KeyValueDiffers;
    private _ngStyleInstance;
    protected _styler: StyleUtils;
    /**
     * Intercept ngStyle assignments so we cache the default styles
     * which are merged with activated styles or used as fallbacks.
     */
    ngStyleBase: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleXs: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleSm: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleMd: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleLg: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleXl: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleLtSm: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleLtMd: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleLtLg: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleLtXl: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleGtXs: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleGtSm: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleGtMd: NgStyleType;
    ngStyleGtLg: NgStyleType;
    /**
     *  Constructor for the ngStyle subclass; which adds selectors and
     *  a MediaQuery Activation Adapter
     */
    constructor(monitor: MediaMonitor, _sanitizer: DomSanitizer, _ngEl: ElementRef, _renderer: Renderer2, _differs: KeyValueDiffers, _ngStyleInstance: NgStyle, _styler: StyleUtils);
    /** For @Input changes on the current mq activation property */
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void;
    ngOnInit(): void;
    /** For ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush and ngOnChanges() updates */
    ngDoCheck(): void;
    ngOnDestroy(): void;
    /**
     * Configure adapters (that delegate to an internal ngClass instance) if responsive
     * keys have been defined.
     */
    protected _configureAdapters(): void;
    /**
     * Build an mqActivation object that bridges
     * mql change events to onMediaQueryChange handlers
     */
    protected _configureMQListener(baseKey?: string): void;
    /** Build intercept to convert raw strings to ngStyleMap */
    protected _buildCacheInterceptor(): void;
    /**
     * Convert raw strings to ngStyleMap; which is required by ngStyle
     * NOTE: Raw string key-value pairs MUST be delimited by `;`
     *       Comma-delimiters are not supported due to complexities of
     *       possible style values such as `rgba(x,x,x,x)` and others
     */
    protected _buildStyleMap(styles: NgStyleType): string | import("./style-transforms").NgStyleMap;
    /** Initial lookup of raw 'class' value (if any) */
    protected _fallbackToStyle(): void;
    /**
     * Special adapter to cross-cut responsive behaviors
     * into the StyleDirective
     */
    protected _base: BaseDirectiveAdapter;
}
```

Comment: which version of typescript ?

Comment: Locally : "typescript": "~2.7.2"

Comment: try this ```"typescript": "~2.9.2"``` in package.json and ```npm i``` again, would that help.

Comment: Should manually change the ts version in json file and run the command? @fatemefazli

Comment: yeah, it's OK .

Comment: i think the issue is gone, thank you!, If you can post it as an answer I can close the question, or should I self answer it?

Comment: you'r welcome i will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on [issue](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/827) The import syntax is new for TS, and only works with TS 2.9. The workaround is to bump to TS 2.9 as well while we consider options internally.so try to update ts:

```
"typescript": "~2.9.2"
```

in package.json and `npm i`  again.